# Help in solving $y' - \frac{y}{t} = b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I think the integrating factor is $r(x)=e^{\int \frac{1}{t}dt} = e^{ln|t|}=t$.

Multiplying the DE by the integrating factor to get $$ty' - \frac{y}= bt$.

Here $x(t)=t$, so $(x(t)y)'=(ty)'=bt$.

So $\int \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}(ty) dt= \int bt dt$.

By integrating, I get $y=\frac{bt}{2}$.

However once I check the solution, it doesn't match. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: mistake in integrating factor : $$e^{\int \color{red}{-}\frac{1}{t}dt}$$

Comment: Remember from what I wrote yesterday, the form of the equation is

$$y' + p(t)y = q(t)$$

(notice it's _+_ $p(t)$). So here, your $p(t) = -\frac{1}{t}$ as $$y' - \frac{y}{t} = y' + \bigg(\frac{-y}{t}\bigg) = y' + \bigg(\frac{-1}{t}\bigg)y = b$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrating factor should be $e^{-\int\frac{1}{t}dt}$ therefore you should have $r(t)=\frac1t$.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating Factor IF$=e^{-\int\dfrac{1}{t}dt}$ which gives IF$=\dfrac{1}{t}$. So the solution becomes

$y\times \dfrac{1}{t}=\int\dfrac{b}{t}dt$

$\implies \dfrac{y}{t}=b\ln t+c \implies y=bt\ln t +ct\quad \square$